# Use typehead.js with autocomplete

Tags: jquery

I am implementing typehead.js with autocomplete in my MVC application. I want both autocomplete and create tabs functionality with typehead.js.

How to do this? I successfully implemented tabs but left with autocomplete. Please help me to implement this.